# <bound method NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.... HELP! **Replacing Missing Values with the Median**

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The column showed in the pictures below had missing values and I was trying to replace them with the median. I don't know if it worked or not but it keeps on displaying **<bound method NDFrame._add_numeric_operations** I have no idea what this means and it can't be good since it was suppose to show the median values in the place of missing values.

Pictures links:
[bound method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYctQ.png)
[bound method1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6OeY.png)

Comment: You need to call the `median` method: `.median()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.median.html) is a method, not an attribute.

You need to **call** it with `()`:

```
df["LiteracyRate"] = df["LiteracyRate"].replace(np.NaN, df["LiteracyRate"].median())
```

Comment: Okay I don't know how I should call it, I'm new to python. I can call a function but I'm not sure how to call it here.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll do that.